My Vue.js code is displaying Strapi (api) data correctly, but when I refresh the page i have a TypeError : $setup... is undefined
I am displaying some Strapi data using Vue3, and when i save the file it displays it correctly on the page, but if i refresh it i have a TypeError error : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $setup.component_1.imgBg is undefined
Which seems weird to me since it could definitely reach the data since it displayed it ? And it's also displayed correctly in the console if i do a console.log with the same link, even after refreshing.
I have just started working with Vue and Strapi (and in general a beginner) so maybe I am not understanding it properly
I thought it was because it didn't populate deep enough, so i added the strapi-plugin-populate-deep
Here is my script :
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

const page = ref([]);
const component_1 = ref([]);

async function fetchPage() {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/api/landing-page?populate=deep').then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.data.attributes.PageContent[0].imgBg.data.attributes.url);
        component_1.value = response.data.data.attributes.PageContent[0];
    });
}

onMounted(async () => {
    await fetchPage();
});
</script>


And here is my template :
 <h2>{{ component_1.imgBg.data.attributes.url }}</h2>


Try to have a v-if="component_1.length" on your h2 element. Otherwise it will try to display data of something not fetched yet.

Thanks, I don't have the error anymore but it also doesn't display the content at all now, even after saving and refreshing the page. @kissu

Maybe you need to iterate on it with v-for since it's an array? Try component_1[0] first. Also, console.log the content of the response to see if you received everything properly.

is component_1 even an array after assigning the async response data?  even though initialized as an array, based on the template code, it looks more like an object, in which case v-if="Object.keys(component_1).length" may be more appropriate.

component_1 is already the first variable of the PageContent array, and I don't think my issue is where i'm fetching the data, because it finds it no problem, I just don't know why it doesn't when the page reloads. It's trying to display something it hasn't fetched like you said, but why is it ok when i save but not when i reload ? I'm new to all this it's confusing. Thanks for the help though @kissu

Thank you @yoduh, that worked, though i don't fully understand why. I'll look into it.

Please read the Vue documentation and use the Vue devtools to be sure about what is the shape of the data you're using, because the way of iteration on them is always a bit different. Overall, take your time to learn the foundations properly.
